# In pandas I am using uforeports I want to get the state which have shape reported oval...I am getting false as output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am using ufo reports in pandas. I want the state which have shape reported "oval"... so I write:

`ufo.groupby("State").Shape_Reported=="Oval"`

It shows me False as output.. pls help me.pls

Comment: Possible dupe - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you go through the documentation and a few tutorials on using pandas.

However, one way of getting the State of all entries with an "Oval" shape would be:

```
ufo[ufo.Shape_Reported == "Oval"].State
```

Comment: But it doesn't show me output..any other way